# Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: . Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: parsing, exception, json.net, win-universal-app

I'm stuck on this code that returns the exception in the title.
I'm using Newtonsoft.Json 6.0.8 in an Universal App and testing on a Lumia 1520 with Win Phone 8.1, Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

This is the code executed:

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string options;

        string root = Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path;
        StorageFolder localFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(root);

        StorageFile textFile = await localFolder.GetFileAsync("options.json");

        using (IRandomAccessStream textStream = await textFile.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            using (DataReader textReader = new DataReader(textStream))
            {
                uint textLength = (uint)textStream.Size;
                await textReader.LoadAsync(textLength);
                options = textReader.ReadString(textLength);
            }
        }

        JObject obj = JObject.Parse(options);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
    }
```

This is the copy of "options" that is passed to the Parse. It looks like the correct string.

```
options = "﻿{\"id\": \"pippo\"}"
```

I used the same code in other projects and it always worked, but if I create a new project with the same code it fails.

```
e = {Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs}
Message = "Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: ﻿. Path '', line 0, position 0."
```

Anyone could point to where the error is?

Thank you

Comment: Did you set a breakpoint and checked if the 'string options' is set?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?